# Running two TWIMLs

Tags: twilio, zoho

I am running Zoho Phonebridge which generates the following webhook: https://www.zohoapis.com/ctiapi/xml/twiliocall/twilio?zapikey=XXX, but I need to add functionality.  Particularly, I need either VM's to be emailed to me (there's a TWIML for that) or the call transferred after X rings.  Neither capability is a part of PhoneBridge.  My questions are these:

1. Can I grab this code myself and modify it?
2. Can I write my own TWIML and then make a call to this code, or
3. Can I write parallel twiml that does not get in the way of this app?

#3 is by far my top choice, but however done, I need to solve this problem.

Anyone have a suggestion? Asking the Dev is never a good option here.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

> Can I grab this code myself and modify it?

No, this code is part of Zoho's application and would need Zoho to alter it.

> Can I write my own TWIML and then make a call to this code, or

No, Zoho sends the calls into the Zoho interface, so it needs to understand it's own state in order to return the right TwiML. You can't just replace this with your own application.

> Can I write parallel twiml that does not get in the way of this app?

No, Twilio gets the instructions for what to do with the call from TwiML. There can only be one set of instructions at a time, so you cannot provide a parallel set of TwiML

---

I'm afraid that both of the features you want here (voicemail notifications and call transfer after X rings) are feature requests for Zoho PhoneBridge. I would have thought that notifications of new voicemails would be a feature that they provide, but I can see no reference to it in the documentation.

I appreciate that asking for features like this may well take time to come to fruition, but given how deeply PhoneBridge is integrated into the Zoho interface once it is enabled, these aren't just features that you can bolt on to their application.